# setting Width dynamically from the ViewModel in MVC3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik DropDown

```
 @(Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("DropDownList").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:274px"}))
```

for this i have a Viewmodel from which i need to dynamically set the Width of this element as per the changes in the rules like

```
.HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:@model.DynamicWidth"}))
```

is this approach possible? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:" + @model.DynamicWidth}))
```

I didn't checked it.